# Correct type for getting analytical data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following type(just part of it) in elasticsearch:

```
"diff":[
  {"name":"state",
      "oldValue":"online",
      "newValue":"offline"
  },
  {"name":"cost",
      "oldValue":2000,
      "newValue":5000
  }
]
```

The diff type is an array of `name`, `oldValue` and `newValue`. Now, the `oldValue` can contain string values and integer values. I want analytics like timerange from which `cost` was above 2000 or timerange from which `state` was online. There can be hundreds of attributes like this.

The problem is I can give only one type to oldValue and newValue, either string or integer.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this with array of something (since you didn't mention it's nested or object), but I did with a simple field:

```
PUT /some_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "some_type": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "copy_to": "name.int"
        },
        "name.int": {
          "type": "integer",
          "ignore_malformed": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then index some testing data:

```
POST /some_index/some_type/1
{"name":"2000"}
POST /some_index/some_type/2
{"name":"testing"}
POST /some_index/some_type/3
{"name":2000}
```

And testing:

```
GET /some_index/some_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "name.int": {
        "from": 1999
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": ["name", "name.int"]
}
```

And some more testing (for both "versions" of that field"):

```
GET /some_index/some_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {"range": {
          "name.int": {
            "from": 1999
          }
        }},
        {"match": {
          "name": "testing"
        }}
      ]
    }
  },
  "fields": ["name", "name.int"]
}
```